# Understanding CUDA shfl instruction

Tags: c++, cuda

I've read the [Shuffle Tips and Tricks](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3174-Kepler-Shuffle-Tips-Tricks.pdf) paper, but I'm not sure exactly how to apply it to some dodgy code I have inherited:

```
extern __shared__ unsigned int lpSharedMem[];
int tid = threadIdx.x;
lpSharedMem[tid] = startValue;
volatile unsigned int *srt = lpSharedMem;

// ...various stuff
srt[tid] = min( srt[tid], srt[tid+32] );
srt[tid] = min( srt[tid], srt[tid+16] );
srt[tid] = min( srt[tid], srt[tid+8] );
srt[tid] = min( srt[tid], srt[tid+4] );
srt[tid] = min( srt[tid], srt[tid+2] );
srt[tid] = min( srt[tid], srt[tid+1] );
__syncthreads();
```

Even without CUDA, this code is rather dodgy, but looking at [this implementation](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/blob/master/src/winner_takes_all.cu) I see:

```
__device__ inline int min_warp(int val) {
    val = min(val, __shfl_xor(val, 16));
    val = min(val, __shfl_xor(val, 8));
    val = min(val, __shfl_xor(val, 4));
    val = min(val, __shfl_xor(val, 2));
    val = min(val, __shfl_xor(val, 1));
    return __shfl(val, 0);
}
```

This code might be callable with:

```
int minVal = min_warp(startValue);
```

Thus I can replace my rather dodgy `volatile` with the above code. However, I cannot really understand what is going on; can someone explain if I am correct, and what exactly is happening in the `min_warp()` function.

Comment: Take a look at this https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the description of `int __shfl_xor(int var, int laneMask, int width=warpSize);`:

> __shfl_xor() calculates a source line ID by performing a bitwise XOR of the caller's lane ID with laneMask: the value of var held by the resulting lane ID is returned. (...)

The lane ID is the thread’s index within a warp, from 0 to 31. So the hardware performs a bitwise XOR for each thread:  sourceLaneId *XOR* laneMask => destinationLaneId

For instance, with thread 0 and:

```
__shfl_xor(val, 16)
```

> laneMask  = 0b00000000000000000000000000010000 = 16 (decimal)
>
> srclaneID = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000 = 0 (decimal)
>
> XOR----------------------------------------------------------
>
> dstLaneID = 0b00000000000000000000000000010000 = 16 (decimal)

Then thread 0 gets the value of thread 16.

Now with thread 4:

> laneMask  = 0b00000000000000000000000000010000 = 16 (decimal)
>
> srclaneID = 0b00000000000000000000000000000100 = 4 (decimal)
>
> XOR----------------------------------------------------------
>
> dstLaneID = 0b00000000000000000000000000010100 = 20 (decimal)

So thread 4 gets the value of thread 20. Etc...

If we go back to the actual algorithm, we see that it's a parallel reduction where a `min` operator is applied. At step:

1. 32 threads acumulate their values into the lower 16 threads.
2. 16 threads acumulate into the lower 8 threads. (The other threads don't matter for the actual algorithm)
3. 8 threads acumulate into the lower 4 threads.
4. 4 threads acumulate into the lower 2 threads ...

PD: Be aware that the two codes are not exactly the same. This offset of '32' tell us that your shared memory array is 2*WARP long. (you are reducing 2*WARP values into 1)

```
srt[tid] = min( srt[tid], srt[tid+32] );
```

And the shuffle one reduces WARP values into 1.

Answer (score 3):

There's an intuitive diagram on these slides page 27 here:

http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2017/presentation/s7622-Kyrylo-perelygin-robust-and-scalable-cuda.pdf

xor 1 first swaps odd/even single inputs

xor 2 then swaps odd/even pairs of previously swapped inputs

xor 4 then swaps odd/even quads

etc.

Another way of doing it would be to compute a full xor mask and xor the original input value. There are many ways of accomplishing this with different warp shuffle instructions. This xor pattern is also used in FFT/DFT transform is also known as the "butterfly diagram".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram